# How do I save the "state" of console

Tags: c#, save

For example,

```
switch (UserInput)
{
    case 1:
        Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
        break;
    case 2:
        Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
        break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Default case");
        break;
}
```

If user input '2' and the program write "Case 2". How do I save that state so when the user opens up the program again it still displays "Case 2" and not other messages?

Comment: That's what configuration files are for.

Comment: Is the user selecting configuration options here, and therefore these need to be parsed and stored in a configuration (as per @Nyerguds ) or do you want the application to start up display the same text as it did the last time it was run (so logging the console text as a user history)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Console doesn't have a state. You could do something like this:

```
public void WriteState(string state)
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("Your Path to your File"))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(state);
        }
    }

    public string GetState()
    {
        string saveText = "";
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Your Path to your File"))
        {
            string text;
            if ((text = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                saveText += text;
            }
        }
        return saveText;
    }
```

If you have any transaction to your console, use the WriteState Function.
If you restart your Application use the GetState Function

Comment: Why `+=`? No need for a string concatenation operation there. Just replace it.

Comment: if he would save more stuff for example - it would make sense otherwise he can delete it by himself of course

Comment: Actually, if each line is a specific setting, it'd make more sense to read each of these lines into a _separate_ string variable.

Answer (score 0):

A console by design does not have a state, One way to work around this is to save the selected state to a text file or database of some kind

Comment: I don't see how the need for persistence through config files would be limited to console applications...